# UITableViewCell viewWithTag how do I figure out which cell is being edited?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with cells that contain a text view... I'm setting them up using this initially, but using the viewWithTag:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

UITextView *tv = [cell viewWithTag:2112];
```

What I'm confused about is how to capture that one specific cell is being edited.

In my edit handler, how do I get the cell that the text view being edited is in?

The edit handler for the TextView won't have the context of the cell it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign tag to UITextView like

```
UITextView *tv = [cell viewWithTag:2112];
[tv setDelegat:self];
[tv setTag:2000+indexPath.row];
```

and in UITextView delegate method get know which cell is begin edit

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
     if (textView.tag == 2000)//for first cell
     {
         ....
     }
     else if (textView.tag == 2001)//for second cell
     {
         ....
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why so many people use tags like this. You"ll have cleaner code if you make a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, and add `IBOutlets` to any `UI` elements you need access to, like the text view in this case. Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, give the text view a tag that's equal to the `indexPath.row` so you can query the text view for that tag, and thereby get the indexPath of the cell. Adding a subclass of `UITableViewCell` involves no more than adding `IBOutlets` and hooking them up -- there's often no need to put anything in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the UITextView and add a property named `@property (nonatomic, strong) id customData ;`, store the indexPath in the customData, then use the indexPath to find the cell.

Alternatively, just store the cell in customData but you maybe use weak instead of strong `@property (nonatomic, weak) id customData ;`.